# Flutter: Appending / streaming data to secure storage item

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-secure-storage

I am developing an app in Flutter that loads files from a server and saves them to secure local storage for later offline use.

I am running into issues with larger documents (e.g. a 150megs PDF), resulting in OutOfMemoryError s on Android.

Is there a way to "append" bytes to a secure storage item or have something like a streaming approach?

Thanks!

Update: I am using the "flutter_secure_file_storage" package.

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_file_storage/flutter_secure_file_storage.dart';

final localStorageManager = LocalStorageManager._(
    FlutterSecureFileStorage(const FlutterSecureStorage()));

class LocalStorageManager {
  final LocalStorageItemMap<DocumentContent> documentContents;
  
  LocalStorageManager._(FlutterSecureFileStorage secureStorage)
      : storageVersion =
            LocalStorageItem(secureStorage, key: "storage_version"),
        settings = LocalStorageSettingsItems._(secureStorage),
        login = LocalStorageLoginItems._(secureStorage),
        documentContents =
            LocalStorageItemMap(secureStorage, "document_contents_");
```

Comment: what is "secure storage item"? what package are you using for securing your data?

Comment: @pskink thanks, I added more detail to the question.

Comment: Is the intent to encrypt the files at rest? Or just to store the files locally for offline use?

Comment: @JaredAnderton both actually. I want to store them locally for offline use, and they need to be encrypted due to their confidentiality (documents that lawyers carry with them).

Comment: and why don't you use some low level cryptographic packages like https://madewithflutter.net/the-best-encryption-packages-for-flutter/?

Comment: @pskink I might look into this. It would require some kind of symmetric encryption, and storing (or deriving) keys is always a concern. I wanted to leave the crypto to some well-tested and established concept.